# Complicated laravel mix

Tags: laravel

The issue with the Laravel mix is absolutely crazy thing.
Months ago I had issue compiling scss files and I could not change the backround color.
I copied my project and when I am running `npm run dev` the backround color does not change again...

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.sourceMaps()
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

app.scss

```
@import 'variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

_variables.scss

```
// Body
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;


// Typography
$font-family-sans-serif: "Nunito", sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 0.9rem;
$line-height-base: 1.6;

// Colors
$blue: #3490dc;
$indigo: #6574cd;
$purple: #9561e2;
$pink: #f66d9b;
$red: #e3342f;
$orange: #f6993f;
$yellow: #ffed4a;
$green: #38c172;
$teal: #4dc0b5;
$cyan: #6cb2eb;
```

I tried run:

```
body {
    background: red !important;
}
```

but does not effect but months ago the only thing which worked.

npm run dev results:

```
        ╷
   compiled successfully
    Notifications are disabled
    Reason: DisabledForUser Please make sure that the app id is set correctly.
    Command Line: C:\MAMP\htdocs\sueliswebsite\laravel_ui-main\node_modules\node-notifier\vendor\snoreToast\snoretoast-x86.exe -appID "Laravel Mix" -pipeName \\.\pipe\notifierPipe-55288728-ce72-4ef8-82b8-0ddb58804c61 -p C:\MAMP\htdocs\sueliswebsite\laravel_ui-main\node_modules\laravel-mix\icons\laravel.png -m "Build successful" -t "Laravel Mix"
```

*Also tried remove the nodes file and reinstalled.*

Comment: delete `node_module ` folder and reinstal npm ,  `npm audit fix` not forget

Comment: That long error output is a red herring. It doesn't seem to be related to the issue. Is the background colour the only thing that does not work? Also when you say it doesn't work do you mean it uses the bootstrap defaults or are those ignored as well?

Comment: @apokryfos No, everything I write in it does not compiling(does not work).

Comment: @MohammadrezaGolshahi already did that and everything.

Comment: Check the network tab, make sure the file in `public/css/app.css` is being loaded

Comment: @apokryfos not at all

Comment: Check if the file `public/css/app.css` is generated to begin with. If it's not generated at ll then try using  the `.scss` extension when importing it in your app.scss. If it is generated then do share how you are importing it in your view

Comment: @apokryfos <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

Comment: Check the browser network tab (usually by pressing F12). Look for the request that loads the CSS. Check if there are any errors and whether the correct contents are loaded.

Comment: @apokryfos at-rule or selector expected at app.css

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled all installed extensions in Chrome and I have now changed the color!
SOLVED

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it permanently,

1. Remove `Enable` key from the `Registry`,
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Laravel Mix
2. Find `wpndatabase.db` from the below path, and open with any of your DB editors (I used HeidiSQL)
   `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications`
3. Check the `NotificationHandler` table and identify `Laravel Mix` under `PrimaryId` column. Just delete the entire column.